# Dynamically creating jQuery Dialog box & append it to DIV . Dialog is created but not within the DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('.image').draggable({
    revert:'invalid',
    helper:'clone',
});
$('#content').droppable({
    accept:'.image',
    drop:function(event , ui{
        $('<div>').appendTo('#content').dialog();               
    }
});
```

**Dialog gets created but not within the CONTENT div. It gets created under the body !**
*why it doesn't append under CONTENT ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this Blog post may help explain it better than I can
http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/jQuery-Understanding-the-chain

> jQuery always references the first element in the chain, unless you
>   use a command that explicitly changes the chain.

If anyone has a reference to the above quote on the jquery site please post it as I would also like to refresh my knowledge on that one ..

**UPDATE:**
Actually the above may not be your problem (left in as its still valid) it seems that Dialog itself has some issues as to where it actually gets added see here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dialog-will-move-its-div-tag-to-body

These seem to have been resolved, so it does depend on your version of jquery UI  see here: 
http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo

```
$('.image').draggable({
    revert:'invalid',
    helper:'clone',
});
$('#content').droppable({
    accept:'.image',
    drop:function(event , ui{
        $('#content').dialog({ appendTo: "#content" });               
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dialog()`-function moves it out of the `#content` div. Created a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L75PL/), where just a regular (non dlg) div is inserted into #content -> works. Then i inserted another div in the html (non-javascript) and made that a dialog -> moved out of #content